# Difference between addq and movl, then addq

Tags: assembly, x86-64

What is the functional difference between

`addq    (%rbx), %rax`

and

`movl    (%rbx), %ecx
 addq    %rcx, %rax`

in assembly?

I think they do the same thing, but what is the functional difference?

Comment: The second example changes ECX, the first one doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one pulls a *full* quadword (64 bits) out of memory at location `rbx` and adds that to the `rax` register.

The second pulls a *longword* (only 32 bits) from that same location and stores it into `ecx` (zeroing the top half of `rcx`). Then it adds `rcx` to `rax`.

So I would say the main difference is that the second snippet is not adding the full quadword in memory to `rax`, only the longword.

The first (one-liner) code sample would be more akin to:

```
movq    (%rbx), %rcx
addq    %rcx,   %rax
```

although even *that* is not strictly identical since it changes `rcx`. To make it an even closer match, you could save and restore `rcx` as part of the process:

```
push    %rcx
movq    (%rbx), %rcx
addq    %rcx,   %rax
pop     %rcx
```

Although then, of course, you've changed `rsp` (albeit temporarily) and it requires you to have a stack actually set up (likely, but not *absolutely* the case) so you may be better off just sticking with the one-liner :-)

Comment: If you do this in GNU C inline-asm, push/pop will clobber the [tag:red-zone], and there's no way to tell the compiler that you want to do that.  So just use the one-liner and tell the compiler about register clobbers, instead of saving/restoring yourself!

Comment: @Peter, you may be right, I haven't looked into that aspect, mostly because the OP makes no mention of using `asm` keywords within C - I assumed, based on the question and tags, it was pure assembly.

Comment: Right, that's what I was thinking, too.  But as a general recommendation for other contexts, it's relevant.  Maybe you're writing an assembler macro: clobbering the red-zone is a nasty side effect for a macro, and harder to debug than clobbering a register.  Better to just take a tmp register as a macro parameter if one is needed.